# I have HTML comments being wrapped in Li and P tags :(

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have content that is first `htmlentities` and then `stripslashes` followed by `nl2br`.

This means a watermark at the end ends up as:

```
<li><p><!-- watermark --></p></li>
```

Not very useful. I have the code below to try and strip the html comments and stop it displaying but its not very good at it!

```
$methodfinal = str_replace('<li><p><!--', '<!--', $method);
$methodfinal2 = str_replace('--></p></li>', '-->', $methodfinal);
echo $methodfinal2;
```

anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Could you state what your expected output is?

Comment: he wants to eliminate empty [li][p] from the output, i guess

Comment: so $methodfinal2 would echo
<li><p>content</p></li>
<li><p>content</p></li>
<!-- watermark -->
<ol>

Comment: just where any <!-- x --> is concerned yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
following Zed's and your comments I've done some testing and this is what you should use:

```
$final = preg_replace('/<li><p>[\s]*?&lt\;!--(.*?)--&gt\;<\/p><\/li>/m', "<!--$1-->", $z);
```

Here is a breakdown of the RE:

```
<li><p>
```

this is obvious

```
[\s]*?
```

because you have a few spaces and a newline between the `<li>` and the comment, but we want the least number of newlines so we use the non greedy *? (it sould work with * as well)

```
&lt\;
```

need to escape the ;

```
!--(.*?)--
```

again we use *? so we would match only this line (other wise if you had the same line again it wold match from the first one to the last one

```
&gt\;<\/p><\/li>
```

same as above

```
/m'
```

so php would treat newlines as whitespace (i am not sure about this but it seems to be working)

Comment: So now we can only hope for not having a > sign in the comment ;)

Comment: Daniel, it's not working, because your html source is incorrect. The comment have &lt;!-- and --&gt; on the sides instead of < and >.

Comment: @Daniel, Zed is right please do not use what i wrote. @Zed you are right, i should have used non-greedy ?* but i don't have any way of testing this now. sorry.

Comment: so $final = preg_replace("/<li><p>(&lt!--[^>]*--&gt;)<\/p><\/li>/", "$1", $original); wont work?

Comment: anyone hazard a guess? it shouldnt be too difficult to preg_replace two tags?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$final = preg_replace("/<li><p>(<!--.*-->)<\/p><\/li>/", "$1", $original);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zed:

Lets be more caring:

```
$final = preg_replace("/<li><p>(<!--.*?-->)<\/p><\/li>/", "$1", $original);
# use .*? every time over .* unless you specificly want what it does
# .*? matches as less as it can
# .* matches as much as it can
```

even better:

```
$final = preg_replace("/<li><p>(<!--[^\-\>]+-->)<\/p><\/li>/", "$1", $original);
# [^\-\>]+ will look for any character that is not - or > 
# so will perform faster
```

Just trying to advocate better regex practice. Hope this helps.

Comment: well the FINAL winning statment was:

preg_replace('/<li><p>[\s]*?&lt\;!--(.*?)--&gt\;<\/p><\/li>/m', "<!--$1-->", $original);

can it be improved in the same manner?

Comment: There is no point using <b>[\s]*?</b>. You should use <b>\s*</b>. 

If you had a set of characters like say spaces or digits, you could use [\s\d] or [\s0-9]. To make it match more than single character, use + (1 or more) or * (zero or more) or ? (none or one) after it. Then think about using *? to match zero or more, (match as minimum as possible). 

You can understand \s*? is not as sensible as .*?

So use \s+ (at least one space, may be more ) or \s* (zero or more space) or \s? (zero or one space) here.


preg_replace('/<li><p>\s*&lt\;!--(.*?)--&gt\;<\/p><\/li>/m', "<!--$1-->", $original);